# How do I detect free fall event on Motorola MC3100 scanner?

Tags: windows-ce, handheld, motorola-emdk

I've searched Google and come up with nothing.  There's tonnes of pages that tell me that the Motorola MC3100/MC3190 support free fall detection and event logging, but I can't find anything in the documentation or online to say how to achieve this by writing your own app and hooking into the event or if there's a log file somewhere on the device that already contains these free fall events.

How do I detect free fall event on Motorola MC3100 scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free fall event is handled by Motorola Interactive Sensor Technology (IST), the software for which comes pre-installed on hardware that supports it.

Unfortunately, the model we have is MC3190-SI4H04E0A – The digit before last determines if the device is capable of ITS or not.  I – means it’s capable. 0 – means it’s not capable.  So our device doesn't support IST.

If the device had this functionality, I would have seen an IST Settings control panel under "Start – Settings – Control Panel – IST Settings".

Answer (score 0):

This can *only* be a Motorola-specific solution. Windows CE doesn't have native free-fall function detection api.

Have you checked the [Motorola 3100 Platform SDK](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC3100_US-EN)? If it is not there, then you will probably need to contact Motorola technical support